# How to accept github invitation?

Tags: github

I received invitation for github but he provided with link let's say https://github.com/example/example2/invitations.

But when I try to access the link , it's giving me page not found error.

Is there any method that I need to pull this email to accept the invitation or the invitation link is simply not working?

I have logged into my git account but still it's not accessible.

Comment: GitHub is a company which provides service around git. Is the invitation for GitHub itself (are you creating an account) or with a project within the website (invited to join a project named example .. in your example ..)?

Comment: Yes it's invitation for a project within the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I try to access the link , it's giving me page not found error.

Then your best bet is to ask the person who invited you to send you a new invitation. Perhaps they moved the project to a different repo or took some other action that invalidated your invitation, and they just need to send you a new one.

Comment: Yes. Resending invite resolved the issue. Thank you for your time. :)